# Если выбран неверный вариант print('Error') если верный продолжить выполнение программы

Tags: python, математика

```py
import math
variant = int(input('Вариант: '))
if variant == 1: 
    x = [-7.2, 3.14, -2.5]
elif variant == 2:
    x = [-4, -3, 9.15]
elif variant == 3:
    x = [3.14, -3.4, 0.59]   
else:
    x == 0
if x == 0: 
        print('error')
else:
    a = x
    for i in a:
        if abs(i)>math.pi:
            print(i)
```

При выборе 4+ варианта пишет ошибку:

> 'name 'x' is not defined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не хотите вместо

```
else:
    x == 0
if x == 0:
```

написать

```
else:
    x = 0
if x == 0:
```